# Ubuntu SSH tunnel to server

Tags: server, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

I used to have my PC on Windows and use Putty to forward internet traffic so it would get through my VPS (located in another country) and give me the opportunity to look like I'm located there whenever I needed it. I would connect putty to my server, define a dynamic port forwarding, and then change Firefox settings to use this port as a proxy.

I do not have the slightest idea on how to do this from my fresh Ubuntu install. Can anyone help?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: related: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455757

Comment: I think this is off topic here, the question is about Windows, PuTTY in Windows, etc. However here is Linux's guide: https://www.systutorials.com/944/proxy-using-ssh-tunnel/ ... The conception should be the same.

Comment: @pa4080: Did you read "how to do this from my fresh Ubuntu install" ?

Comment: @RoVo, yes, I read also the first part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a socks proxy with `ssh` command with `-D` option.

> **-D [bind_address:]port**
>
> [...] allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.
>   Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to determine where to connect to from the remote machine. Currently the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act as a SOCKS server.

Example:

```
ssh -D 8080 username@sshd_server
```

After that, set the browsers proxy option to use socks5 proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. ([via](https://www.systutorials.com/944/proxy-using-ssh-tunnel/))

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for, thanks !